# Is there a feature like LiveJournal's "cut"?

Tags: support, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a <spoiler> tag that makes hidden-until-you-click text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text)

Is there something like LiveJournal's "cut" feature on the Stack Exchange platform? Basically, it's a tag that lets part of the content to be hidden by default, and then when you click a link, it expands. I want that tag to hide supplementary content that's only relevant to a small number of the people reading my questions.

Comment: possible...there seems to be opposition to "spoiler" tag because having it called "spoiler" encourages people to ask puzzles instead of questions, maybe lj-cut equivalent is more appropriate