# Implement the <spoiler> tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, spoilers

Please consider implementing the [request for some sort of a spoiler markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text) using the following syntax:

```
why did we trust <spoiler>rchern</spoiler> ? WHY OH GOD WHY?

<spoiler>
The cake is a lie.
</spoiler>
```

I propose `<spoiler>` over the modified blockquote syntax `>!` [proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text#comment-9333) by [Nick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1490/nick) because:

- a `<spoiler>` tag can easily be inlined; the `>!` syntax cannot.
- a `<spoiler>` tag can easily be ignored when rendered through external services that don't actively support it
- a `<spoiler>` tag can be parsed with jQuery, which is a great and does all things™

Comment: I'm not entirely serious about the jQuery bit :)

Comment: Nick's comment: *It would be nice if the format could fall back on standard markdown if someone does not have this feature: e.g., `> this is blockquote` and `>! this is spoiler`. Parsers which don't understand spoilers will just show it as a blockquote with leading `!`* (Just for future reference, as [linking to comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment/27319#27319) is not officially supported and even upvoted comments [might be hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex/1732454#1732454) and hence non-linkable.)

Comment: [spoiler](http://www.google.com/search?q=this+is+a+nice+workaround+to+just+externalize+the+spoiler,+but+I+agree+that+a+data+URI+would+be+nicer)

Comment: @mario: [spoiler](http://www.example.com/ "or hide the spoiler in title text")

Comment: Use ruby on rails and your website will literally build itself!™ Oh wait, that joke's not funny anymore...

Comment: Note that the current Markdown implementation, when rendered on SE sites, still allows for jQuery magic given its CSS class: `<blockquote class="spoiler">`.

Comment: Since imp shouldn't be `status-completed`?

Comment: @bobobo Not in the form I proposed it with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add markdown support for hidden-until-you-click text (aka spoilers)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers)

Comment: Not a duplicate, @Chris. That post just wants spoiler functionality, but this one wants a specific syntax that is different than the current implementation.

Comment: @Pop - fair enough, just let the flag expire.#

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This [has been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396) in spirit, but as the `>!` syntax instead. We really don't want to be in the business of making up new HTML tags; it's already confusing enough mixing HTML with Markdown arbitrarily.

The syntax is

```
>! This is spoiler text
```

Examples

> This is spoiler text

<s>This is not yet reflected in the preview pane.</s>

Essentially, a blockquote where each line begins with a `!` will be a spoiler.

Spoilers have the same text color as background color, but can be revealed by hovering over them (or selecting the text).

Comment: can that be extended to chatmarkdown by any chance? Us `Talkative` folks would like to have it ;) ... lemme guess, 6-8 weeks?

Comment: There should probably be some sort of indication in the box that you need to mouse over to see hidden text, or users will just be confused (or posters will need to explain it every time it gets used)

Comment: @michael if there are complaints this is "too hard to use" I will just pull it. It's a SPOILER TAG. Bad usability is THE POINT.

Comment: Well, I was rather surprised you implemented it at all :)

Comment: There are several issues with the `>!` markdown, including a lack of support for inline spoilers and [bulleted lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116613/351462).

Comment: This answer seems largely an explanation of *how* the spoiler tag is implemented rather than a consideration of *why* the implementation is preferred. Even the claim that it's "already confusing enough mixing HTML with markdown" would be great to hear considered more deeply in addition to other justifications for the implementation..

Comment: can spoiler tags be used on an embedded YT video?