# Spoiler Markdown shows up as normal blockquote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, spoilers

In the question *[What was Dooku's plan for the Battle of Coruscant?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/what-was-dookus-plan-for-the-battle-of-coruscant)*, I used the `>!` syntax to create a spoiler section, but it shows up as a normal blockquote with a `!` at its start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to extend the spoiler Markdown across all of the lines. For instance,

```
>! *PALPATINE*: Good, Anakin, good. I knew you could do it. Kill him. Kill him now!  
>! *ANAKIN*: I shouldn't . . .  
>! *PALPATINE*: Do it!!  
>! Anakin cuts off Count Dooku's head.
```

renders as

> *PALPATINE*: Good, Anakin, good. I knew you could do it. Kill him. Kill him now!
>  *ANAKIN*: I shouldn't . . .
>  *PALPATINE*: Do it!!
>  Anakin cuts off Count Dooku's head.

Comment: Ah, you answered while I was looking for [a citation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup).

Comment: @PopularDemand Ah, good find. I had somehow forgotten about that thread. The original one introducing the feature isn't as detailed.