# Markdown not appropriately rendering unordered list spoilers

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, list, spoilers

A user in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14928/1913 discovered that he couldn't create a spoiler unordered list, and I can't seem to either.

I can blockquote an unordered list without any real issue:

> - 1
> - 2

Or the following (similar to the solution in [Spoiler Markdown shows up as normal blockquote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107978/spoiler-markdown-shows-up-as-normal-blockquote)):

> - 1
> - 2

However, if I introduce a spoiler, it breaks:

> !- 1
>   - 2

Or:

> - 1
> - 2

I've tried nesting blockquotes, which doesn't seem to help either. Is this a bug? If not, how in *tarnation* do I create a spoiler-wrapped unordered list using Markdown?

Comment: I suspect we're not supposed to be doing that. I usually restrict myself to plain text without markup in spoilers, to avoid any problems. The spoiler syntax was a pretty late addition, it's not part of the Markdown spec as far as I know.

Comment: Should this be [meta-tag:feature-request], then?

Comment: Possibly...Since the `>!` thing is a custom extension, I suspect the Markdown parser gets tripped up by what it sees as a stray `!`...not sure off hand what could reasonably be done about that. I'd have to check the code to see if that's the issue to begin with, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can successfully use raw HTML a la `<ul><li></li></ul>`. It's a bit ugly though, as it introduces empty paragraph tags and is less pleasant to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

May be you could do something like this.

- Create the ordered/unordered list.
- Then introduce the spoiler markdown on each line.
- Then wrap the ordered list with *pre* tag.

Not the prettiest solution but at least a workaround.

> ```
> 1.One
> 2.Two
> 3.Three
> - One
> - Two
> - Three
> ```

[image: Spoiler with ordered or unordered list]