# Allow bulleted lists to be used in spoiler tags

Tags: feature-request, markdown, spoilers

I want to use spoiler tags to hide a bulleted list, but the formatting doesn't seem to be working properly.

**Can an option be added for using spoiler tags `!` with a bulleted list?**

This is apparently a longstanding issue as [originally reported in 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129441/351462). It would be helpful if a workaround was implemented.

---

**Failed Attempts**

`> - Spoiler`

> - Spoiler

`>! - Spoiler`

> - Spoiler

`> !- Spoiler`

> - Spoiler

`> - !Spoiler`

> - !Spoiler

`!> - Spoiler`

!> - Spoiler

Comment: I tried a few things in the answer box, and I would add that numbered lists and code blocks are also not working in the spoiler box at the moment, though I could have sworn I'd seen code blocks in spoilers before...