# Spoilers broken?

Tags: bug, markdown, spoilers

We can make multi-paragraph blockquotes by skipping a line in between:

```
> First paragraph

> Second paragraph
```

> First paragraph
>
> Second paragraph

but when you try to do this with spoilers, this is what you get:

```
>! First paragraph

>! Second paragraph
```

> ! First paragraph
>
> ! Second paragraph

Is this supposed to happen? I'm a little annoyed with having to type `<br><br>` every time.

Comment: You need the Spoiler tag on every line. Cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107980/338924