# Why does the Wayback Machine not show our text inside spoiler code?

Tags: discussion, archive

See [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20210605115643/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup). Why does the [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine) not show our text inside spoiler code? Can't the SE team do something about it?

Comment: No repro here Firefox 89.0 (64) on win 10. Spoilers show just fine in wayback for me. Tested with Chrome: 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit) on win 10, still works fine. What browser are you using, addons etc.?

Comment: It shows up just fine for me. Maybe you're trying to click it before the page fully loads?

Comment: Maybe you need to "accept all cookies" - :(

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 91 on Android.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. more likely blocked JS, cookies are not related here at all.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

It works for me - though, there's a *slight* delay before reveal spoiler turns up. In any case, Way Back Machine/Internet Archive (IA) is separate from Stack Exchange, so there is not much the developers here can do 'formally' should something be broken. On the other hand -  nothing's broken on IA's side from what I can tell. I'm running [Vivaldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivaldi_%28web_browser%29) (which is the same engine as Chrome - so chrome-likes should work), but I'm wondering if you have something turned off, or if it's a browser-specific issue.