# Spoilers don't support block formatting (and so don't format well)

Tags: feature-request, markdown, spoilers

While trying to assist with the formatting of a [question which spoilers a list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42515/1980), I discovered there's not a lot of parity between how spoilers and quote blocks (which are superficially quite similar) handle nested Markdown formatting.  (Simple HTML works fine.)

For example, here's a variety of typical Markdown nested inside a quote block:

> #### heading
>
> ---
>
> paragraph
>
> ```
> code block
> ```
>
> - nested
>
>   1. list
>
> > even nested quotes!
> >
> > - with nested nested formatting!

Aside from the code and quote blocks not standing out due to matching background colors, everything works exactly as expected.  Sadly, the same is very much **not** true for spoilers:

> ### heading
>
>  ---
>
>  paragraph
>
>      code block
>
>  - nested
>  1. list
>
>  > even nested quotes!
>  >
>  > - with nested nested formatting!

Eek!  Any chance of changing spoilers to act more like quotes?  Needing complex formatting in spoilers isn't a *terribly* common scenario, but when you do, the inconsistency is jarring and a bit frustrating.

Comment: Generalizes [Paragraphs breaks are ignored inside spoilers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112793)

Answer (score 19):

HTML, baby.

> #### heading
>
> ---
>
> paragraph
>
> ```
> code block
> ```
>
> - nested
>
> 1. list
>
> > even nested quotes!
> >
> > 1. with nested nested formatting!

<strike>Yes, okay, not everything hides (looking at you, `<hr>` and `<code>`)... but that's a different bug report, now, isn't it?</strike>

(On Meta Gaming, where this post came from, the above made two nested *spoiler* blocks where the inner area is only visible on hover of the *inner* block. The same thing happens in the mobile version of MSO, but not here.)

Comment: So because the less common forms of styling work poorly, we shouldn't be concerned that the more common forms don't work at all?  Not a very satisfying solution. :-)

Comment: @Ben I'm proposing HTML as an uncommon solution to an admittedly uncommon problem. Personally, everything that gets in the way of abuse of spoiler tags is a positive thing in my book. Notice that Markdown's syntax for non-paragraph-level formatting (italic bold code etc.) still works.

Comment: I'm just seeing the `<hr>`. The `<code>` section is hiding just fine here (FF 5 [good gravy, I need to update] Win7).

Comment: @PopularDemand Hence the paragraph I've added in parentheses. As I said, that's a different bug report that _does_ belong to meta gaming.

Comment: Hm, okay. Perhaps it'll make more sense to me after I get home (work started blocking Gaming SE).

Comment: Caveat: this spoiler tag is unreadable on the chat.SE android app.

Comment: 2016: markdown still doesn't work, code blocks are hidden, `<hr>` still isn't. Oddly enough, if you go to the revisions page of this post, the inner block also appears on hovering anywhere inside the main block, but requires hover on it here on the post itself.

Comment: This _is_ a common problem on Puzzling. We use spoilers for all of our answers.

Comment: Seems both the horizontal rule and the code block are hidden by the spoiler tag now.

Comment: This doesn't work for tables today. Table support was added recently, but *only when using Markdown*; the `<table>` element is still explicitly unsupported. This thus doesn't work in that case.

Comment: I get a _"Hasta la vista, baby"_ vibe! or like this: _They asked me to upgrade to Windows 8, but I said....


I still love Vista, baby!_