# How do you make advanced spoilers?

Tags: support, markdown, posting, spoilers, blockquote

Is it possible to make spoilers inside blockquotes?

```
> text
> more text
> >! spoilery text
> text
> more text
```

How about multiline spoilers?

```
>! Spoiler
>! Mor Spoilerz
>! Still spoilery
```

Finally, quotes inside spoilers?

```
>! Spoiler
>! > The spoiler said stuff
>! > The spoiler had more to say
>! More spoiler
```

It specifies none of these on the Formatting page, but the syntax is so similar between blockquotes and spoilers, so I don't know if it's possible

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268813/can-advanced-spoilers-be-implemented) feature request linked to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make spoilers inside block quotes. It just needs a little extra space:

```
> text
> more text
>
> >! spoilery text
>
> text
> more text
```

Produces:

> text
>   more text
>
> > spoilery text
>
> text
>   more text

Multi-line spoilers and block formatting, like quotes inside spoilers are not supported, [unless you are using HTML code for formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116614/245360).

> text
>   more text
>
> > spoilery text
> >  line 2
>
> text
>   more text

Comment: `...are not supported.`  And are not needed.  I'm not sure about other sites that use spoilers, but on SciFi.SE I've _never_ seen a situation where enhanced spoiler formatting would make a question or answers significantly better.

Comment: @Ward They are often used on Puzzling.SE, where one wants to give a hint that doesn't need to be visible in the beginning. They are also used on answers, at least to short questions, so that the answer is not visible to people who what to solve the puzzle themselves.

Answer (score 4):

You may add a multiple-line spoiler using `<br>`:

> this really all has to be hidden 
>  hence the multiple line spoiler

Or just use your second example putting two spaces or `<br>` after each line (except the last one).

Comment: If I could accept both answers, I would. Thanks for the help!