# Can advanced spoilers be implemented?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, posting, spoilers

From [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268810/how-do-you-make-advanced-spoilers), it was suggested that advanced spoilers be implemented, such as multiline spoilers and block elements (like quotes) inside spoilers. Can these features be added?

Adding this would make writing spoilery quotes, such as from a book, but keep those who wish to stay uninformed (like me :D) unspoiled.

Comment: When writing up a feature request, it's customary to explain how said feature request might benefit the community.

Comment: In the question, I added a reason why this should be implemented, like @RobertHarvey suggests/