# Markdown Tables in spoilers

Tags: bug, markdown, spoilers

Markdown tables do not work in spoilers (they do in blockquotes) with the standard syntax. In my mind this should be supported, so I think it's a [bug] rather than a [feature request] :). I tried to circumvent that via writing the table in HTML syntax, which **actually works** in the preview when editing:

```
>! <table class="s-table"><thead><tr><th style="text-align: center;">Header 1</th><th style="text-align: center;">Header 2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="text-align: center;">Foo</td><td style="text-align: center;">Bar</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

[image]

But when you **actually post** it, it looks like this:

<sub>(Spoiler with HTML syntax)</sub>

> Header 1Header 2FooBar

In blockquotes, they work with standard markdown:

> | Header 1 | Header 2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | Foo | Bar |

Comment: Yes, I reported that (kinda) at the announcement post.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look for answers in there. Too bad that this isn't supported.

Comment: Well, now that I actually looked at it it's technically not a duplicate since this is about tables within spoilers rather than spoilers within tables, but I already accepted the close request. This is probably [status-bydesign] as well anyway :)

Comment: Yeah, that is by design as well: see [Spoilers don't support block formatting (and so don't format well)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-support-block-formatting-and-so-dont-format-well). I've requested that the duplicate target be changed to that.