# Previously introduced badges due to the positive effect during winterbash

Tags: discussion, support, badges, winter-bash

Yesterday I read about the positive effects of the winter bash firstly during its runtime and secondly because new badges can be tested or introduced which worked well during the bash. I am particularly interested in the second part.
*(I sadly cannot find the post that included that statement)*

Therefore my questions are:

- **Have there previously been new badges introduced after the winterbashs of the past years?**
- **Which ones?** *(Resulting of which hats?)*
- Are there already candidates for new badges resulting of this year's winterbash or is it too early for that?

Comment: It has been considered for the Red Baron hat in this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247415/should-we-make-the-red-baron-hat-trigger-a-permanent-badge

Comment: Another one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159430/implement-a-badge-similar-to-the-winter-bash-cake-is-not-a-lie-hat?rq=1

Comment: @wythagoras feel free to post them as a answer, I will certainly give you an upvote for the answer, probably not accept it but that at least partially answers my question :)

Comment: I originally posted the first comment as an answer, but it was converted to a comment.

Comment: @wythagoras that is possible :O

Comment: And damn it, should have asked this question via the app :/ one of the more useless badges ;)

Comment: Maybe you were inspiring: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271915/can-we-add-a-badge-having-similar-criteria-as-weed-eater-hat

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been suggested thrice earlier:

- Weed Eater Hat, 2015: [Can we add a badge having similar criteria as Weed Eater hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271915/can-we-add-a-badge-having-similar-criteria-as-weed-eater-hat)
- Red Baron Hat, 2014: [Should we make the Red Baron hat trigger a permanent badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247415/should-we-make-the-red-baron-hat-trigger-a-permanent-badge)
- Cake Is Not A Lie, 2012: [Implement a Badge Similar to the Winter Bash "Cake Is Not A Lie" Hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159430/implement-a-badge-similar-to-the-winter-bash-cake-is-not-a-lie-hat?rq=1)

Others can be found by searching:

```
[badge-request] and [winterbash*] is:q
```