# Can we add a badge having similar criteria as Weed Eater hat?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, winter-bash-2015

I suggest that we turn the Weed Eater hat of Winter Bash 2015 into a permanent badge. I'm not sure what name it should be given, or what color the badge should be.
Perhaps we can introduce several levels of this badge, depending on the number of answered and accepted Tumbleweed questions.

This hat rewards answerers that seek out questions with low visibility and provide the asker the answer they were looking for (hence getting the answer accepted).

Since my very first post on the entire Stack Exchange network brought me my very first badge - Tumbleweed - I like the idea of rewarding such behavior.

The exact requirements for earning the hat, taken from [balpha's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271032/191412) are :

> Here are the exact requirements for the hat:
>
> - The answer was posted during Winter Bash and is not a self-answer.
> - The answer is accepted, has a score of at least 1, and is not deleted.
> - The question is fully active (not closed, not deleted, etc.).
> - At the time when the answer was posted,
>
>   - the question was at least 7 days old,
>   - there were no (active) comments on the question,
>   - there were no (active) answers to the question, and
>   - the question had a score of 0.

I think we can relax the requirements a bit. I'm not sure that a score of at least 1 is necessary, since the OP of the question may not have enough rep to upvote, and we are talking about a question with low visibility, that is not likely to attract votes.

Can you think of any reason why adding such a badge may cause any undesired behavior?

EDIT :

Just to add some data - when I tried to get the Weed Eater hat, I searched for recent questions for which Tumbleweed badge was awarded. I found a question that probably would have gotten a lot more attention if it was tagged properly. It was given a single "small" tag (30 followers, 359 questions), which resulted in almost no views in 7 days. Had the major language tag that this question belongs to been used, it would have probably been answered within minutes. In this case, actively searching for a Tumbleweed question led me to a perfectly answerable question that only suffered from bad tagging.

Comment: I would post an answer, but I'm going to wait a week to get a badge. (Kidding, I don't actually think anyone will do that.) (Real suggestion: badge tier is silver.)

Answer (score 3):

Agreed.

Lots of Tumbleweed questions are often ignored and never to be seen nor answered in a very, very long time so this should help those lonely users get some justice (and answers) they deserve. Similar to balpha's requirements, the requirements should be:

- Answer a question that gave the OP the badge, Tumbleweed
- There was no recently active activity (>= 7 days since most recent activity)
- Score is at least 1 or accepted

The score should be at least one upvote or the accept to show that the answer did help the OP in someways. The tooltip would be:

> Answer a question that had no recent activity in the last seven days and has met the requirements of Tumbleweed. Your answer must be at least a score of 1 or is accepted.

Tumbleweed should be a big factor in this badge since this badge should be aimed to answer questions with not so much activity, which means that it would most likely fit the requirements of Tumbleweed.

To prevent people from waiting like seven days before anyone answers, let's make this a silver badge and change the tooltip:

> Answer 25 different questions that had no recent activity in the last seven days and met the requirements for Tumbleweed. Your answer must have a score of at least 1 or is accepted.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem of people waiting 7 days before answering. If that was the case, nobody whould answer anything unless there's a bounty on it. In addition, this badge should also be based on low view count, so if enough people viewed the question, even if they didn't comment or answer, it would still be disqualified from earning anyone this badge.

Answer (score 1):

I vote no.

This would be a lesser version of the [Revival](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/126/revival) badge.  Roughly, the revival badge is for getting **2** upvotes when no one has answered for 30 days.  Your suggested badge is roughly for getting **1** upvote after 7 days.  They aren't exactly the same, but there is clearly a family resemblance.  Moreover, the revival badge is bronze, so since the new badge is lesser, it should be sub-bronze.  Because there is no such thing, I don't think this is worth doing.  (By contrast, the `favorite question` -> `stellar question` sequence starts with silver, so it would make sense to add a lesser version as bronze.)

Comment: There's one important component that the Revival badge lacks. That's the low number of views - low views = small chance that anybody who knows the answer actually looked at the question. The total lack of comments in Tumbleweed questions also matters, since often people get their answer from comments and then nobody bothers to post an answer even though the problem was solved. Finally, the suggested badge will be awarded based on acceptance criteria, not upvotes. I think that's an important distinction between that badge and Revival, since it shows the the OP found an answer to their problem.

Comment: I acknowledged that they aren't *exactly* the same, but clearly there is a family resemblance. Whether adding the requirement that the OP accepts the answer is "important" is a matter of interpretation. To my eyes this is a slightly different variation on the same theme; there is no need for another badge here.