# Add a way to reveal all spoiler blocks in a post at once

Tags: feature-request, spoilers

Over at [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), we [require](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/should-we-aggressively-delete-answers-that-contain-no-explanation) all answers to contain explanations.  For riddles, what usually happens is that the answerer will post an explanation within a spoiler block for each line of the riddle.  This can result in several spoiler blocks within the answer (here is a [typical example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6043/4450)).  Someone who wants to read the answer to a riddle may have to click several times to reveal all of the spoiler blocks.

I propose a new feature to allow a user to automatically reveal all spoiler blocks in a post at once.  Perhaps there can be an "spoil" link at the bottom of a post next to the "share", "edit", and "flag" links.  When a user clicks on "spoil", all spoiler blocks within that post will be revealed.  Of course, a user could still click on an individual spoiler block to reveal just that block.

Comment: Here, have some jQuery: `$('.spoiler').css('color', 'inherit')`. Converting this into a user-friendly clickable thing is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Unspoiling something would be to hide it, or to not have it shown in the open

Comment: @random Good catch.

Comment: Inline spoiler blocks would also be a good idea for Puzzling...

Comment: @randal'thor A good idea, but they [rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69573/implement-the-spoiler-tag) an inline spoiler request.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a userscript to do this, don't know if one already exists, but here it is:

```
$('#answers div[id*="answer"], div[id*="question"]').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.post-menu').append('<span class="lsep">|</span><a id="showSpoiler-' + $(this).attr("id") + '" href="javascript:void(0)">unspoil</span>');
});
$('a[id*="showSpoiler"]').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).attr('id').split(/-(.+)?/)[1];
    $('#'+x+' .spoiler').css('color', 'inherit'); //for normal text
    $('#'+x+' .spoiler a').css('color', '#0000FF').css('text-decoration', 'underline'); //for links
    $('#'+x+' .spoiler code').css('color', '#222').css('background', '#eee'); //for markdown
    });
```

I've added it to my 'Additional Features' userscript at [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features)

Comment: An easier solution would be `$(this).closest( '.answer, .question' ).find( '.spoiler' ).removeClass( 'spoiler' )`; this is how the standard SE spoiler click handler does it. Also, if you want to make that [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch)-compatible, add `.end().find( 'soup-spoiler' ).addClass( 'visible' )` to that.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You're right! I didn't think of that - I just tried to remove what `spoiler` does (I seem to like to complicate things). I'll change that in a bit (as well as on the stack apps post)