# Make both sides of the edit show a spoiler at once

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, spoilers

When looking at edits in the "side-by-side" view, spoilers are hidden as they are usually and get shown on mouseover. However, I only have one mouse, so I can't see the old and the new at once.

It would be better to let the spoiler on one side also make the one on the other side appear.

An alternative (or addition) to this would be [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249808/add-a-way-to-reveal-all-spoiler-blocks-in-a-post-at-once) feature request.

Answer (score 5):

This is already possible in a way that lets you see **all** spoilers at once. Simply click each spoiler to cause it to not disappear. (Clicking again returns it to normal.) This works in both edit histories and while viewing posts normally—and probably everywhere else you'd see a spoiler.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that also worked on desktop. :D I'll not mark this as accepted for now, because it would still be a nice feature, just way less important than I thought.

Comment: This is a useful feature to know, but it would still make sense to implement what's suggested in the question.