# PHP version of the markup used for the stackexchange?

Tags: support, markdown-rendering, markdown, markdown-preview

Is there a php version of the markup used for the stackexchange, more info on the mark up at [Stackoverflow's Markup](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious is [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).

That said, this is based on the original [Markdown project by John Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), so won't necessarily contain the various improvements made by the SO team.

Whilst not directly relevant, there are some good blog posts and podcasts regarding the history and specific implementation of markdown on SO:

- [Coding Horror: Responsible Open Source Code Parenting](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/responsible-open-source-code-parenting.html)
- [StackOverflow Podcast #79](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/podcast-79/)

*(Remembers how much he enjoyed the podcasts. Becomes momentarily maudlin. Etc.)* ;-)

Comment: Do you know any lighter versions, maybe with less featues? this should be as simple as a single preg_replace don't you think? Though it may contain a large array.

Comment: @middaparka Can you please remove your answer i wish to remove this question, Thanks

Comment: @JamesM Why? (If it's deemed off-topic, etc. it'll be removed real-soon-now.)

Comment: As an aside: I think many, if not all, of the Stack Exchange improvements are kind of backward compatible. Like [the spoiler syntax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396) renders fine (kind of) in other renderers.

Comment: @JamesM Incidentally, it's **vastly** more complex than "a single preg_replace". :-)

Comment: (@James, I hope it's not your habit to remove questions once they have been answered. That is not only annoying, but also kills communities like this. See also [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471))

Comment: @middaparka : I want this question as I want to remove this question and then make another question with the real question that I intended for, just did not know how to word it, in other words i want to start fresh for this question.

Comment: @JamesM Just open a new question - this isn't the way MSO works. (Did you read the link @Arjan posted?)