# StackOverflow disables jQuery if you post a code snippet with a jQuery reference

Tags: bug, status-declined, google-chrome, jquery

I posted this snippet of code as an [answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589579/facebook-like-notifications/5589661#5589661) on StackOverflow:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

When I posted it, I got a message that said `Stack Overflow works best with jQuery enabled`, leading me to think that whatever script protection that's built in was disabling the wrong jQuery. I'm not sure if this is a known issue or a won't-be-fixed issue, I just thought I'd bring it up in case no one else had.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the message I get after posting (it happened with this question too):

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Browser: Chrome 11, OS: Mac OS 10.6

Comment: I've seen this message before because an extension I have sometimes screws with it, but this one is no-repro for me.

Comment: I just posted my browser information and disabled all my extensions and I was still able to reproduce this issue. Are you using the same browser/OS?

Comment: Chrome 11 is in beta, we don't support beta browsers...as they're often *their bug*, not ours....which is the case here.

Comment: Fair enough - feel free to close this if necessary.

Comment: @Jimmy: No.  Chrome 10 and Ubuntu 10.04 here.

Comment: No repro with Chrome 11.0.696.34 beta on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I can reproduce in Win7 Chrome 10 latest

Comment: This can happen in Safari too, see [December 2010 comments here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#comments-71396).

Comment: @Jon, I guess it's actually a WebKit thing. (Or at least: the same can happen in Safari.)

Comment: @Arjan: Okay; I'm not familiar enough with this. My aim was to put a tag on it so future issues can be tracked for when the browser is out of beta (like we did with the IE9 tag). Could you retag to make it appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: Even more, Chrome 11 *is* the current version, @Jon, no longer a beta ;-) (I'll see if I can find some confirmation about WebKit.)

Comment: I think the point here is that the SE sites *used* to work on any accused browsers, so it’s **not** the browsers, it’s the site.

Answer (score 7):

I could [repro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsjWg.png) it in my chrome 12 dev too, but I think this is chrome 11+? specific, because of XSS Protection Heuristic algorithm, which rejects scripts that included when you submit the form data.

[image]

(Stack Overflow also using jQuery1.5.1 at the moment)

If you change version of jQuery to 1.5.2 or 1.5 in your post, it won't happen.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: I hope that XSS protection is a little smarter by the time they release.

Comment: @balpha, yep, they could have checked that as special case like "if the script data, send through form request, already included in original page, let the script run", but don't know there is flaws in my idea though.

Comment: Similar things can happen in Safari too, see [December 2010 comments here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#comments-71396).

Comment: I just got this in Chrome 17.0.963.46 beta-m in suggesting an edit to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122141/jquery-on-blogoverflow-should-be-served-from-cdn/122142#122142 -- same thing shown in console, too.