# jQuery on blogoverflow should be served from CDN

Tags: support, status-completed, jquery, blog-overflow, cdn

On most Stack Exchange sites, jQuery is served from the Google CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

On [Blog Overflow](http://blogoverflow.com) sites, jQuery is served from the site directly. Not only that, it's served from each `*.blogoverflow.com` subdomain directly, instead of from a central location. This means that whenever a user visits a different SE blog, they have to redownload the jQuery script all over again.

```
<script type='text/javascript'
 src='http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'>
</script>
```

For performance reasons, the blog overflow template should be altered to use the Google CDN version of jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voila - and so it has been done.