# Which wiki syntax is used on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, markdown, technology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

I've seen a lot about Markdown here, but I haven't seen any direct answer.

Could you ensure me that Stack Overflow uses the Markdown wiki syntax?

If yes, which rendering library (from Markdown to HTML) is used?

Comment: There are similarities, but markdown does not qualify as wiki syntax. What separates wiki markup are non-numeric page names with an immediate/flat mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network#10370), Stack Overflow uses [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/).

Comment: Also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help is titled "Markdown editing help" and starts with "Markdown help". So indeed, Markdown, with some enhancements [such as spoilers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396).

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for the comment, I was not aware of spoilers. Test:
>! Probably not in comment-mode?

Comment: Some other enhancements: plain URLs are rendered clickable on these sites, and inter-word emphasis like `hello_my_world` is not enabled.

Comment: @Arjan HTML can be used for that purpose `hello<em>my</em>world` (not in comment mode though: hello<em>my</em>world).