# Please indicate reputation that exceeds the cap on the rep graph

Tags: feature-request, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-graph

I've had a great week on superuser

[image]

Now, on at least one of those days, i've gotten better than the 200 rep the rep cap allows me, due to bounties. However, its pretty hard to tell

Now, lets say we coloured the rep that has been capped off and we showed rep as "added rep + capped rep" when one hovers over it, it'll make it easier to see how much rep has been achieved. Would this be a plausible/desirable feature? Could we have this, if it is??

[image]

Comment: Aslong as it's not red. How about the neutral orange-ish color? Red is already used for rep losses, I think it would cause confusion.

Comment: I just picked a random colour, and i'd used red last, to draw the famous free hand red circles. Colours would probably depend on site anyway.

Comment: I think this would just be depressing for people like Jon Skeet.  Seeing that they lose far more rep than they gain due to the rep cap =)

Comment: John Skeet would probably need a wall of monitors to see his rep ;p

Comment: Nice. Only if coloring would really be too much, then maybe [the mouse hover](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt4WX.png "Jon Skeet's, not mine...") could show some more. And while at it, seriously, maybe some line to separate rep from each post? Like to see if the bar is just a few posts, or many posts? And, maybe also on the graph that's on the summary page? (That currently has no 200-point line either, though hovering reveals some info there too.)

Comment: (With that grey bar in your screenshots, you fooled me into [hovering for a spoiler](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396), despite it not being full width.  `;-)`)

Comment: Oh, its just what i thought of offhand. Breaking down the rep into types would be neat too (Vote-Rep at the bottom, Accepted answers on top of that, Bounty on top). That wouldn't necessarily need different colours, just lines seperating them.