# "Spoiler Alert" option when making post

Tags: feature-request, spoilers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add markdown support for hidden-until-you-click text (aka spoilers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers)

Let's be honest. There's nothing worse than checking your news feed and accidentally finding out the result of your favorite TV show or sporting event that you've PVR'ed/recorded. Checking my Facebook has become second nature... most of the time I forget to think whether or not there could be posts that I don't want to see/discuss yet!

The spoiler alert option allows people that have seen the show/movie/sporting event to still discuss it, while keeping the lazy/busy bums like me safe from spoiling an outcome. (Also could have a "disable" function for people who don't want to use it at all.)

It could be like: (click the little spoiler alert button)

Spoiler alert subject: Dexter Season Finale

"Holy crap! I can't believe Dexter killed that dude!"

And would show up on all news feeds as

"Dexter's season finale spoiler"
Or
"Spoiler alert: Dexter's season finale"

And just click the "reveal" button or something.

Comment: This has been implemented already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396

Comment: Dude, could you be, like, less informal and stuff? I mean it's cool and all but, yeah! I'm just sayin'.

Comment: It should be called "A Half Quora"

Comment: i think you might be on the wrong meta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[We already have that!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396)**

> Isn't it awesome! 
>  You can see it... 
>  ...with a hover over!

I think this is what you mean, but I don't completely understand.

Comment: I think the OP means to hide the title in the question feeds. This has not been implemented.

Answer (score 4):

As Oded mentioned in the comments, [we already have a spoiler feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/166017). Some sites, like [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) and [Scifi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), use it extensively. Basically, anything in the spoiler mark-up is hidden (text color = background color) until you mouse over it.

I'm not sure if that's what you're asking for or not; you'll need to edit your question if you have something different in mind.

Comment: I think the OP means to hide the title in the question feeds. This has not been implemented.

Comment: In that case, the feature will probably be declined. We have spoiler markup for viewing the full text of the question, and our communities are usually pretty nice about putting spoilers in question titles. That seems like plenty of help preventing spoilers.

Comment: Plus having a front page with a bunch of hidden titles would be pretty terrible. How would you know which questions you might want to read?

Comment: @Laura Fair enough, I was just trying to clarify the OP's question. I am not a member of any communities where spoilers are an issue, so for all I know this might be a terrible idea, but you could also consider using a spoiler tag that people can ignore.

Comment: @Asad We *could* do that, but it's not in line with how our tag system was designed and used. "Spoiler" would be a meta tag, and [we hate meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: (It also wouldn't be a very good solution. If I ignore the [tag:spoiler] because I haven't watched the most recent season of Dexter, great -- but what if I *have* watched the most recent season of Boardwalk Empire and want to talk about it (but finale questions are tagged [tag:spoiler]? And how long after the airing of the tv show does it qualify as a "spoiler" to discuss it? I think this is a problem that is actually impossible to solve in a way that is meaningful and clear for all users.)

Comment: Clearly what I'm talking about has not been implemented. As a WJHC game was just ruined for me! Haha I'm talking about the ability to make any post somewhat spoiler proof, whether it'd be set from the person making the post or the one reading it. Maybe my original post wasn't informative enough ;). Maybe we're over thinking it. Who needs the term "spoiler" involved. All I know...if I'm pvring something, I don't check Facebook. Just thought it'd be cool to somehow prevent ruined endings!