# >! notation in markdown editor

Tags: support, markdown, spoilers

What is the reason why you can do this?

> When hovering you can see the text.

This is the markdown code I used:

```
>! When hovering you can see the text.
```

Comment: That's the spoiler markup, mostly useful on sites like Gaming, SciFi or movies.

Comment: @MadScientist: in what situations you can use this? I'm a stack overflow user so I've no idea why to use this.

Comment: see also [Add markdown support for hidden-until-you-click text (aka spoilers)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called a 'spoiler markdown'. It is used to hide portions of the text which are only revealed if you hover over it.

It is useful in Stack Exchange if you want to [ask about a movie](http://movies.stackexchange.com) (for example) but do not want to spoil key elements of the plot for anyone who may to have seen it.

Spoiler markdowns are also used for things like riddles or quizzes. These types of question aren't really a common thing in Stack Exchange, but with markdown text, you would be able to ask a question and folks would be able to hover over the hidden text to reveal the answer.

Comment: On Stack Overflow I've seen that also used for homework solutions.