# Using spoiler to have better answers

Tags: discussion, answers, spoilers

I recently asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226499/show-that-bx-y-and-by-x-are-isometrically-isomorphic/). That was a homework problem; the response people gave was very nice, but in one answer they basically solved it for me. That was the most useful answer. I think there is no mechanism such that people are encouraged to use spoiler tags.

Ideally I would like that the person just gives an intuition of the answer and post the solution within spoiler tags. So when I or other people looking for similar questions could have the ability to try it ourselves first.

Comment: There is already a mechanism for this. You can use `>!` in front of the text you want to keep invisible until it is hovered over. Making sure that people *use* spoilers is something else entirely.

Comment: I think Maria already knows how to do spoiler markup, but wants other users to actually use it.

Comment: @Glorfindel That's not clear from the question—and you mentioned the same thing in your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add markdown support for hidden-until-you-click text (aka spoilers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers)

Comment: I agree, @Glorfindel.  Furthermore, this question is as clear as day. The close reason is quite a stretch.

Comment: Maria:  I would suggest you ask this on the meta site for math.se, being careful to make clear how you can encourage answers which provide hints, using spoilers against which to question your answer.  Many folks here (and many of the downvoters) aren't familiar with the use of spoilers in answers, and so "unclear what you are asking" reflects their confusion, not yours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want just a hint, not a complete solution, *just state so in the question.* Other users **don't know** you want just a hint **until you tell them**; most users *are* looking for complete solutions (up to the point where Math.SE has a special close reason for [problem statement questions without context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), but I digress ...)

I can imagine that there are still users who want to give a complete solution (remember that they're not just answering for you but also for other people who want to know the answer!). For them, you could include a link to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/295232) which explains how to do spoiler markup (not everybody knows this, it's a rather hidden feature until you see it being used).

Your question only says "How should I think about this?" but that's IMHO too vague.
Something along the lines of

> **Please note**: I'm first of all just looking for a hint. If you do want to give a complete solution, use spoiler markup (`>!`) to hide it. For more details on how this works, see [this answer on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/295232).

would be fine, I guess.

Comment: I'm of two minds on this; questions are supposed to help more than one person, so deliberately *not* solving the problem at the behest of the asker seems to do a disservice to our future readers.

Comment: @fbueckert Hints can help others too.

Comment: @fbueckert A description of how to solve a problem, rather than a dump of the code from the question but with some small change to fix a problem, is often *more* likely to be applicable to future readers.

Comment: @Servy Hints and how to solve a problem can be two very different things, depending on who sees it.  It can often be just giving a vague direction, describing a step or two, or giving the full explanation of how to solve a problem.  I agree that explaining how to solve the problem is going to be more useful than just solving the problem.  I disagree that is always what a hint means.